# How to use DescribeSObjectResult to fetch SObject field information

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I've to fetch all 10 fields of a custom Object `My_Object__c` and store it in a `Map<String, String> labelMap` // 1st string is the label and 2nd string is the Field Name

I know by using `DescribeSObjectResult` we can fecth all Sobject and it's field information.

But, how will I implement that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Map<String, String> labelMap = new Map<String, String>();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe  = My_Object__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();
for( String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet() ) {
    Schema.SObjectField field = fieldMap.get( fieldName );
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();
    labelMap.put(fieldDescribe.getLabel(), fieldDescribe.getName() );
}
```